# How to mock a non instance method in python?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a test case where I have to mock a non instance method, when I mock an instance method it working fine but the same if I try for a non instance method I am not able to mock it. The method gets executed.

Instance method (woking fine) :

common.send_email

```
class Email:
    def send_mail(self):
        print("sending email")


def send_mail_2():
    print("sending mail 2")
```

common.test_mocking

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from common.send_mail import Email, send_mail_2

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('common.send_mail.send_mail_2')
    @patch('common.send_mail.Email.send_mail')
    def test_send_email(self, mock_instance, mock_non_instance):
        mock_instance.return_value = 1
        mock_non_instance.return_value = 1
        res = Email().send_mail()
        assert res == 1
        res1 = send_mail_2()
        assert res1 == 1
```

Here, mocking the send_mail works but mocking send_mail_2 failing.
how can we mock send_mail_2() method?

Comment: send_mail_2 is not a method, it's a function

Comment: The problem is that you are not mocking the same function reference you are using, see [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6). As you call `send_mail_2` directly (which does not make much sense, as you are only testing the mock), and you import it the way you do, you have to use `@patch(__name__ + '.send_mail_2')` to make it work.